# font-awesome icon - onmouseover event change color

Tags: css, asp.net, font-awesome, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an ASP.NET gridview control, with a font-awesome trash icon in the end column.

On *mouseover* I want the color to change to red, and back again to default *onmouseout*.

Here is the `template field` in the asp.net gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span ID="lnkDelete" style="border:none" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Performance Review?')"
                    runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="fa fa-trash-0" 
                onmouseover="this.style='color:red;'"    
                CommandName="Delete">
                <i  class="fa fa-trash-o" onmouseover="script:this.style='color:red; font-size:24px'"  onmouseout="script:this.style='color:black; font-size:24px'"
                    style="font-size:24px;"></i> 
            </span>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and in IE it is rendered as

```
<span id="ctl00_m_g_10488b48_1486_45be_8a9c_efc307c0cb4b_ctl00_grdPR_ctl04_lnkDelete" style="border: currentColor;" 
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Performance Review?')" CommandName="Delete" ItemStyle-CssClass="fa fa-trash-0">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size: 24px;" onmouseover="script:this.style='color:red; font-size:24px'"></i> 
                    </span>
```

but I am obviously getting it wrong as nothing changes when I hover over the trash-can icon.

I have also tried using the css `hover` style in my page, but again, nothing happens:

```
<style>
.fa fa-trash-o{
  color: black
}
.fa fa-trash-o:hover{
  color:red;
}
</style>
```

so where am I going wrong?

Comment: correct the selector `.fa.fa-trash-o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by only CSS. The problem is you are using wrong selector in the css. The `fa` and `fa-trash-o` classes are in the same element. So you need to remove the space between `fa` and `fa-trash-o` and put `.` before them as they are classes

```css
.fa.fa-trash-o {
  color: black
}

.fa.fa-trash-o:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you - quick follow-up, how to ensure the mouse-icon is an arrow and not a line?

Comment: try `cursor:default;`

Answer (score 1):

see code below you forget `.` before the `fa-trash-o` class :
selector in css:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
.fa-trash-o{
  color: black
}
.fa-trash-o:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<span>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size: 24px;"></i> 
</span>
```